# Install SSL certificates and Virtual Hosts for new domains through API

Tags: wordpress, apache, ssl, digital-ocean, lets-encrypt

I'm trying to create a web app which works kind of like a website 'generator'. It is based upon **Wordpress Multisite** and an API that communicates with Wordpress.

**Wordpress** is installed on a **Digital Ocean Apache server**. The Wordpress API integration works and I can create new sites on Wordpress from my web app.

The problem is when I try to integrate domains into the whole thing. As of now new sites gets created as subdomains, f.eg. *newsite.primarydomain.com* . Now I want to allow my users to buy and use a custom domain, and my idea was to use the **Namecheap API**. However, I cannot for the life of me grasp how I should get this to work with SSL and at the same time have *userscustomdomain.com* as a mock for *newsite.primarydomain.com* .

I have working **Let's Encrypt**-certificates for *primarydomain.com* and **.primarydomain.com* . And I tried using both **A**, **CNAME** and **ALIAS** records which pointed the custom domain correctly, but I got a insecure https warning because the SSL-certificate was issued for *primarydomain.com* and not *userscustomdomain.com* .

I actually got it to work when I did things manually, and installed a new SSL-certificate with **certbot** through my **apache** terminal. That installed the certificate and automatically added an apache **Virtual Host** record. But how do I get all this to work automatically from my web app? In other words, do I need to create vHost-records and install SSL from an API or similar? I'm open to pretty much any solution, small, large, free, paid.

It seems this is a pretty niche problem and would really really apprieciate any pointer in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up ditching Apache and using [Caddy Server](https://caddyserver.com/) instead. It has awesome API support and automatic Let's Encrypt-certificates. Would highly recommend.